# Android Warning: JAR does not exist or contains no resources

Tags: android, jar, location, maps

I am using Maps & Location within my app. And everything is working as expected, there are no issues when testing the app.

However I am seeing the following messages in LogCat:

```
    W/ResourcesManager﹕ Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.media.remotedisplay.jar' 
does not exist or contains no resources.

    W/ResourcesManager﹕ Asset path '/system/framework/com.android.location.provider.jar' 
does not exist or contains no resources.
```

Gradle Related Config:

```
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:7.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:7.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.3.0'
```

Manifest & Permissions:

```
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" android:required="false" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
<uses-feature android:name="com.android.vending.billing" android:required="false" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

<!-- Creating Permission to receive Google Maps -->
<permission android:name="com.myapp.supportmapfragment.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<!-- Permission to receive Google Maps -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.myapp.supportmapfragment.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

<!-- Permission to read Google Services -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"  />

<!--Maps API needs OpenGL ES 2.0. -->
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
```

Additional lines Inside Application Manifest Tag:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="APIKEY" />
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />  
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.globalConfigResource" android:resource="@xml/global_tracker" />
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"  />
```

Should I be concerned about this logCat warning and is it serious? If anyone faced similar warning, how did you get rid of it ?

Comment: Do you solve your problem?